# 'name' AR attribute returning class name and id not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a User object and getting name like this is fine:

```
>u=User.find(1)
>u.name
>jt
```

but it has an association with an object that when I get the user back it returns the name of the class:

```
oc=ObjectConnection.find(1)
oc.user.name
> User
```

and the id is giving me an error:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :063 > oc.user.id
NoMethodError:   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT id, name FROM `users` WHERE (id=1)
undefined method `id' for [#<User id: 1, name: "jt">]:ActiveRecord::Relation
    from /Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:459:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):63
    from /Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :064 >
```

The classes are:

```
class ObjectConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :object_connections
end
```

What is going on? This seems really simple.

thx

Comment: Is the id=1 for the object_connection instance you are referring to?  You are finding the object_connection by its id in the code above, not by the object_connection user's id.

Comment: Are you sure ObjectConnection doesn't have some other implementation of the #user method? The odd things are that #user is returning a relation specifying id and name explicitly in the select clause.

Comment: @numbersnelson - I'm  just showing that it works fine outputting directly.

Comment: @noodl- that was it - feel stupid right now

Answer (score 0):

I have a nearly identical relationship between Contact and Company (Contact belongs_to company, company has_many contacts.)  Here's my rails console (Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.3).

```
1.9.3p125 :019 > company = Company.find(1)
Company Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Company id: 1, name: "Acme Corp", created_at: "2012-03-20 17:49:44", updated_at: "2012-03-20 17:49:44"> 
1.9.3p125 :020 > contact = Contact.find(1)
Contact Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Contact id: 1, first: "Tom", last: "Harrison", email: "foo@example.com", created_at: "2012-03-12 19:11:57", updated_at: "2012-03-20 17:56:37", birthdate: "1962-02-26", company_id: 1> 
1.9.3p125 :021 > contact.company.name
Company Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
=> "Acme Corp"
```

Perhaps there's some case where "name" was used in an earlier version of AREL?  Also, notice the odd SQL syntax `... WHERE (id=1) ...`  What happens if you look for a different attribute of ObjectConnection?

This is an identical situation, isn't it?  Perhaps the version of Rails?  Ruby?  Seems implausible, but the answer is "You're doing it right".